# SWT Text set scroll value

Tags: java, text, swt

In my application I have an SWT text field. I need to set a scroll value (roll the text in the field to the end in my case). How I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should have the desired result without moving the cursor position:

```
text.setTopIndex(text.getLineCount() - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the carat to that position, which will cause the text to scroll to that position.  For example:

```
text.setSelection(text.getText().length());
```